# How do I prevent List::MoreUtils from warning about using $a and $b only once?

Tags: perl

The [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils) module indicates that you use the variables `$a` and `$b` when supplying the `BLOCK` that goes with the `pairwise` function. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw'pairwise';

my @x = ( 1 ..  5);
my @y = (11 .. 15);
my @sums = pairwise { $a + $b } @x, @y;
```

But when I do that, I get warnings like this:

```
Name "main::b" used only once: possible typo at try.pl line 7.
Name "main::a" used only once: possible typo at try.pl line 7.
```

Is there an elegant way to deal with this problem?

**Update:**

See the [answer by Ether](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20108488/55857) for perl v5.19.6 and beyond: problem solved.

Comment: This didn't appear to have been reported previously, so I have just done so at https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=65629

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Depends on what you consider elegant.

```
no warnings qw(once);
our ($a, $b);
```

One of these two will suffice.  You can even limit their scope pretty easily.

```
my @sums = pairwise { no warnings qw(once); $a + $b } @x, @y;
my @sums = pairwise { our $a + our $b } @x, @y;
```

Explicitly specifying the package will suppress the warning too.  If you're in `main`,

```
my @sums = pairwise { $::a + $::b } @x, @y;
```

Comment: This "no warnings" is not necessary - at least in first example.

Comment: If I may quote the line following that code, "One of these two will suffice."

Comment: @Chris Lutz: sorry, my misunderstanding.

Comment: @ephemient Thanks for the response. The last option (specifying the full package) did not eliminate the warning in my example.

Comment: Hmm, it eliminates the warning for me with Perl 5.10.0 (without any `use feature`).  Well, I prefer the `our` method anyhow...

Answer (score 7):

Yep, it's not you.  You can no warnings 'once'; or you can predeclare $a and $b so that they will not be used once anymore.

```
our ($a, $b);
```

does the trick.  I tend to prefer that because it doesn't turn off warnings for anything else, and it's a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably a bug in `List::Util`.

Turning off warnings globally is probably not a good idea, however you could do something like this:

```
{
  no warnings 'once';
  return join("_", @monsters) if @monsters && List::Util::reduce { $a && $b // 0 > 0 } 1,@monsters;
}
```

This would turn off the relevant warning category for that part of the code only.

Answer (score 5):

As of perl 5.19.6, [this warning is disabled](https://metacpan.org/changes/release/BINGOS/perl-5.19.6#a-and-b-warnings-exemption) for all uses of `$a` and `$b` everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Add this near top of your program:

```
use vars qw( $a $b );
```

or, if you don't like the "obsolete" part of [perldoc vars](http://perldoc.perl.org/vars.html), simply add:

```
our ( $a, $b );
```

Comment: I remember somewhere reading that `use vars qw($a $b);` messed with `sort()` but I can't seem to find it in perldoc, so it may just be a figment of my imagination.

Comment: `use vars` is package-scoped while `our` is lexically scoped to the containing block, so from the point of environmental sanitation, I prefer `our`...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a similar module I'm writing. The only solution I've found (other than using functions that use `$a` and `$b` twice, of course) is to put this line somewhere in your code:

```
$a = $b; # hack to disable warnings about "main::a" used only once
```

It basically does nothing, but it does disable the warning. Consider keeping the comment so future maintainers don't have to read your mind.

Comment: I guess you meant `$a = $a` :)

Comment: @pwes - Nope. It's been a while but IIRC it gives the warning about both `$a` and `$b`. `$a = $b` neatly uses both, thus disabling warnings about each of them. Though it is possible that either one could have a value left over from a `BEGIN` block, and the later code _could_ rely on this value (though the thought gives me nightmares), so `$a = $a; $b = $b;` might technically be better.

Comment: OK, I thought you meant to use it inside the block -- in which case it _does_ something :)