# "name used only once" warning while using List::Util::reduce

Tags: perl, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prevent List::MoreUtils from warning about using $a and $b only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490505/how-do-i-prevent-listmoreutils-from-warning-about-using-a-and-b-only-once)

I get a warning like this:

```
Name "main::a" used only once: possible typo at analysis.pl line 15.
```

on this line

```
return join("_", @monsters) if @monsters && List::Util::reduce { $a && $b // 0 > 0 } 1,@monsters;
```

I understand that `$a` and `$b` are not used anywhere else (and why it would be a problem for an ordinary variable), but I'd like to get rid of the warning - after all, it is the [`List::Util::reduce`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) function that will set `$a` and `$b`. It is similar to `sort` function.

Please, don't suggest turning warnings off. This is not something I want to do.